# Why is `speedglm` slower than `glm`?

Tags: r, performance, regression, glm, speedglm

I am trying to use `speedglm` to achieve a faster GLM estimation than  `glm`, but why it is even slower?

```
set.seed(0)
n=1e3
p=1e3
x=matrix(runif(n*p),nrow=n)
y=sample(0:1,n,replace = T)

ptm <- proc.time()
fit=glm(y~x,family=binomial())
print(proc.time() - ptm)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  10.71    0.07   10.78 

library(speedglm)
ptm <- proc.time()
fit=speedglm(y~x,family=binomial())
print(proc.time() - ptm)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  15.11    0.12   15.25
```

Comment: you should explain the context in which you're working.  If you want to do many small GLM fits as fast as possible (a reasonable possibility) you might want to consider using `glm.fit()` directly ...

Comment: @BenBolker I am trying fit a logistic regression with 3 million rows and ~1000 columns, want to see how fast it runs in different package.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The efficiency of `speedglm` over `glm`, is the way it reduces the `n * p`model matrix to a `p * p` matrix. However, if you have `n = p`, there is no effective reduction. What you really want to check, is the `n >> p` case.

---

More insight form computational complexity, in each iteration of Fisher scoring.

`glm` using QR factorization for a `n * p` matrix takes `2np^2 - (2/3)p^3` FLOP, while `speedglm` forming matrix cross product of a `n * p` matrix, followed by a QR factorization of a `p * p` matrix, involves `np^2 + (4/3)p^3` FLOP. So as `n >> p`, `speedglm` only has half the computation amount of `glm`. Furthermore, the blocking, caching strategy used by `speedglm` gives better use of computer hardware, giving high performance.

If you have `n = p`, you immediately see that `glm` takes `(4/3)p^3` FLOP, but `speedglm` takes `p^3 + (4/3)p^3` FLOP, **more expensive**! In fact, the matrix cross product becomes a shear overhead in this case!